# Sequence Execution of Appium Test Cases in TestNG leads to test case failure

Tags: selenium, testng, appium

Below TestNG execution of test cases leads to failure. 
Error - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 56 milliseconds

```
@Test(description = "Test I")    
public void TestI() {

    System.out.println("Test I");
    openApp();
    checkForCondition();
}

    @Test(description = "Test II")    
public void TestII() {

    System.out.println("Test II");
    openApp();
    checkForCondition();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you place all related stuff, not just two methods? I mean the class, where driver is initialized, called etc. Also I would look at your testng.xml file and  pom.xml maven(if you're using it) as well.